# Monitoring GPU usage by FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, nvidia

I have an small http server which receives requests to process some video clips. The server spawns a child process and uses FFMPEG for this. I recently compiled FFMPEG to use GPUs. I am using an Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080.

However I am unable to figure out a way to analyse the memory and other usage statistics of GPUs. I have tried `nvidia-smi`, but it seems to return 0% always.

The question I have is what are some of the best tools that are available for monitoring GPU usage.

Edit - I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and only have remote access. So command-line tools are better.

Comment: I guess it would be good to mention what platform you are on. On Windows 10, for example, Task Manager should be able to [give you this information](https://www.howtogeek.com/351073/how-to-monitor-gpu-usage-in-the-windows-task-manager/)…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that `nvidia-smi` provides various ways to monitor and log gpu stats. `nvidia-sim dmon -f --filename` periodically logs the gpu stats to a file. `nvidia-smi daemon` also does somethin similar